# Rails 4 - how to add for a scope with ".find_by_sql" another scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, scope, find-by-sql

I use a scope like this:

```
# controller

    sales_rep = Car.sales_rep(branch_id)

# model - scope
  scope :sales_rep, -> (branch_id) { 
    find_by_sql("... a big, complicated query ...")
  }
```

This works well so far, but I need to add another "filters", such as:

```
sales_rep = Car.sales_rep(branch_id).by_year(params[:year]).by_year(params[:month])
```

I add the additional scopes to the model:

```
  scope :by_year, (lambda do |year|
    if year.present?
       where('YEAR(s.delivery_date) = ?', year)
    end
  end)
  scope :by_month, (lambda do |month|
    if month.present?
       self.where('MONTH(s.delivery_date) = ?', month)
    end
  end)
```

When I run this code, I get this error:

```
undefined method `by_year' for #<Array:0x007f8203f8a660>
```

How to make accept a `find_by_sql` query another scope query?

Thank you

Comment: You can't. As you've discovered, `find_by_sql` returns an Array, not an ActiveRecord Relation that you can chain further query methods onto. For that reason it's not really appropriate to put `find_by_sql` in a scope. If you want it to be "chainable" you'll have to rewrite it using query methods.

Comment: This might lead you towards a right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25454696/find-by-sql-as-a-rails-scope